# Include HelveticaNeue-Medium in iOS4

Tags: ios, fonts

iOS5 supports HelveticaNeue-Medium out of the box, and I can just set up everything using xibs.

However, the font is missing in iOS4. I tried adding HelveticaNeue.dfont from my OSX directory, and in plist via UIFonts. I tried (for testing) to add a ttf I found online and nothing worked.

Is there a way to get this working without having to manually set each UILabel programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, I was having two conflicting plist files.